# Does submitting to database change the results from query being shown?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code generating the table the person will see (defaults with $date as todays date, $date changes based on a URL variable if they select a future date or past date. $time is just $row[time])

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM times", $db);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ //grab all available times
    $time = $row[time];
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM appts WHERE time = '$time' AND date = '$date' ", $db); //select all appointments that match current date and available times
    $aptid = $apt[id];

    while($apt = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
    {
    $mem = $apt[mem];    
    if($mem != ''){
        $class = 'green';
    }
    $ns = $apt[ns];
    $x = $apt[x];
    if($ns || $x != ''){
        $class = 'yellow';
    }
    echo "<tr><td class='$class'>$apt[date_set]</td><td class='$class'>";
    echo date('h:i A', strtotime($row[time]));
    echo "</td>";
    $aptid = $apt[id];
    echo "<td class='$class'>$apt[name]</td>
    <td class='$class'>$apt[phone]</td>
    <td class='$class'>$apt[phone2]</td>
    <td class='$class'>$apt[src]</td>
    <td class='$class'>$apt[coach]</td>
    <td class='$class'>$apt[v1]</td>
    <td class='$class'>$apt[v2]</td>
    <td class='$class'>$apt[mem]</td>
    <td align='center' class='$class'>$apt[x]</td>
    <td align='center' class='$class'>$apt[ns]</td>
    <td class='$class'>$apt[comments]</td>
    <td align='center'>";
    if($aptid != ''){//i dont want to display options on blank rows
        echo "<a href='index.php?date=$date&apptid=$aptid&action=edit'>Edit</a> &nbsp;
        <a href='index.php?year=$year&month=$month&date=$date&apptid=$aptid&action=x'>X</a>&nbsp; 
        <a href='index.php?year=$year&month=$month&date=$date&apptid=$aptid&action=ns'>NS</a>&nbsp;";
        //<a href='index.php?year=$year&month=$month&date=$date&apptid=$aptid&action=delete'>Delete</a> (HIDDEN FOR NOW)
    }
    echo "</td></tr>";
    }   
}

?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the code for adding a new record to the database

```
<div class='dialog' title='New Appointment'>
    <form id='newappt' method='post'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Time</td>
                <td><select name='time'>
                <? $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM times", $db); //set time option as times available from times db
                   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                    echo "<option value = '$row[time]'>";
                    echo date('h:i A', strtotime($row[time])); 
                    echo "</option>";
                   }
                ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td><input type='text' id='datepicker' name='date'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='name'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='phone'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone 2</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='phone2'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Src</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='src'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Coach</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='coach'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Comments</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='comments'></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type='submit' name='submit-newappt' value='Add Appointment'>
    </form>
</div>
```

then heres what happens on submit:

```
    if($_POST['submit-newappt']){ //when submitted insert new record and display success message.
        $dateset = date("Y-m-d");
        $q = "INSERT INTO appts (date_set, time, date, name, phone, phone2, src, coach, comments) VALUES ('$dateset', '$_POST[time]', '$_POST[date]', '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[phone2]', '$_POST[src]', '$_POST[coach]', '$_POST[comments]')";
        $result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());    
        echo "<br>New appointment added successfully for ";
        echo $_POST['name'];
        echo " at ";
        echo $_POST['date'];
        echo " at ";
        echo date('h:i A', strtotime($_POST['time']));
    }
```

So say i'm currently viewing today, the table will show all appointments with todays date. I then 'add a new appointment' to 7/14/2013. Its changing the table to show the appointments for whatever date i just added an appointment to instead of staying on today.

tl;dr(ish) - why when adding a new record to a database does my php query change?

Date comes from:

```
if(isset($_GET['date'])){
        $date = $_GET['date'];
    }
    if(!$date){
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
    }
```

Comment: Think I snipped your title appropriately

Comment: You are wide open to sql injection

Comment: There's no way to answer this question with the code you've given us. Where are your variables `$time` and `$date` being set? What's the relationship between the two pieces of PHP you've included?

Comment: have you printed out your insert statement to make sure it's correct? you should also validate your POST data - and use mysqli not the mysql_ functions because they have been deprecated.

Comment: @ryanb couldnt be further from correct title

Comment: @AleksG not worried about it, this is an offline app and all fields are locked down. i'll add escaping when im finished but its pointless for now

Comment: @andrewsi added more code

Comment: @user2391454 - the only thing I can think of is that $date is getting re-set. Do you maybe set it in the submit code?

Comment: @andrewsi that's definitely what is happening, the URL doesnt change so ?date= in the url is staying on today or whatever date im trying to view, but somewhere its assigning $date to the date i just submitted

Comment: @andrewsi thats the whole submit code. only place date gets set is from the url or if theres no url it defaults to todays date

Comment: @user2391454 - what code do you use to initialise $date?

Comment: @andrewsi added to bottom

Comment: @AleksG Can you quantify how wide that is?

Comment: @user2391454 - thanks. And what happens after the submit code in the question is run? I'm assuming that there's code that redirects the user to an index page, or something similar?

Comment: @andrewsi it just stays where you are but the dialog to submit is removed

Comment: @user2391454 - so your form posts back to itself on submit? When is the rest of the code run, from the first block of code? I'm still struggling trying to understand how the various code blocks you've posted relate to each other, and when each is running.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO That was sarcasm, wasn't it?

Comment: @andrewsi the whole app is run through index.php with different forms showing up based on $step. &step=add brings up the bottom 2 peices of code. the first peice of code that generates the results is just there all the time

Comment: @user2391454 - what I assume is happening in that case is that the `date` you're setting in the appointment booking page is being picked up by the main chunk of code. Try changing its name to something like `bookingdate` and see if the problem goes away.